# How to add Defined name range to any cell using google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I am doing freelancing project please tell me how to add defined name range to cell using google script

Answer (score 0):

```
function createNamedRange() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rng=ss.getActiveRange();
  if(rng.getWidth()==1 && rng.getHeight()>1) {
    var rngA = rng.getValues();
    var name = rngA[0][0];
    var ro = rng.getRow() + 1;
    var co = rng.getColumn();
    var h = rng.getHeight()-1;
    var w = 1;
    var rg = sht.getRange(ro, co, h, 1);
    ss.setNamedRange(name, rg); 
    sht.getRange(rg.getRow(),rg.getColumn()).offset(-1,0).setBackground('#ffff00');
    ss.toast(rg.getA1Notation(),name);
  }
}
```

animation:

[image]